# (Very) Simple Java 3D graphics library?

Tags: java, 3d

I need a very simple 3D graphics library for a project that I'm working on.

All I need to be able to do is accept a set models in the from of rectangular prisms (boxes) and render them from at least one angle.
Don't need any highfalutin effects: just draw some boxes in 3D.

Any particular suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try and give a look at [Java 3D](http://java3d.java.net/binary-builds.html/)? According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_3D):

> Java 3D is a scene graph based 3D application programming interface
>   (API) for the Java platform. It runs atop either OpenGL or Direct3D.

Answer (score 0):

You can create basic 3D objects with Java 3D API  http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/java3d/

Comment: That link (as of now, Nov. 7. 2014) asks me to accept cookies and then presents me the oracle main page.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a 3D chart library ([Orson Charts](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/)) using pure Java (no Java3D or OpenGL) and I found this book very helpful:

> Computer Graphics for Java Programmers (2nd, 07) by Ammeraal, Leen -
>   Zhang, Kang [Paperback (2007)]

It explains the mathematics with working examples to build up a fairly general purpose (and pure Java) 3D graphics engine.  For anyone with the same requirements as the OP, I recommend this book.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out Abe3D? It's made in pure java and is open source.
And here's the GitHub page if you're interested:
https://github.com/andrewcisco/Abe3D